# Google Maps api vb.net

Tags: vb.net, google-maps

Estou a trabalhar com a *API* da *GoogleMaps*, e estou com o seguinte problema.
Tenho um mapa que funciona corretamente no *IE*:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mudando de browser, por exemplo *Chrome* o mapa fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem alguma sugestão para contornar este problema?

Comment: tem alguma mensagem de erro no js?

Answer (score -1):

Aparentemente não. deixo o javascript

```html
function markiconsHotel() {
    var varArray = $("#HiddenMapa").val();
  
    var _MostraParceiro = 0;
    _MostraParceiro = $("#DropDownListParceiros").val();

    var tempArray = varArray.split('|');
   
    var locations = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
        locations[i] = tempArray[i].split(',');
    }
    var loclat = 0;
    var loclon = 0;
    var arrayLength = locations.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        if (locations[i][1] != "0") {
            loclat = locations[i][1];
            loclon = locations[i][2];
            break;
        }
        //Do something
    }
    //$("#HiddenLat").val(loclat);
    //$("#HiddenLon").val(loclon);

    var contentString = "";
    var _LocNome = "";
    //alert(locations[0][1]);
   // alert(locations[0][2]);
    //initialize(locations[0][1], locations[0][2]);
    //var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][1], locations[0][2]),
    //    zoom: 10,
    //    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    //};
    //var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(loclat, loclon),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    //alert(map);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;
    //alert(locations.length);
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        //  alert(locations[i][1] + " " + locations[i][2]);
        if (_MostraParceiro == 0) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map
            });
        } else {
            if (locations[i][4] == _MostraParceiro) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map
                });
            }
        }
        // novo
        // alert(locations[i][0]);
        _LocNome = locations[i][0];
        contentString = "";
        contentString = '<div id="content">' +
              '<div id="siteNotice">' +
              '</div>' +
              '<h5 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"></h5>' +
              '<div id="bodyContent">' +
              "<img src='" + locations[i][3] + "' width='120' height='120' alt='' />" +
              '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
              'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the ' +
              'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) ' +
              'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km ' +
              '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major ' +
              'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is ' +
              'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the ' +
              'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, ' +
              'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World ' +
              'Heritage Site.</p>' +
              '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">' +
              'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> ' +
              '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>' +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>';


        //var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        //    content: locations[i][0]
        //});
        // fim novo
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent("<div id='content' style='width:100%; height:100%;'><h5>" + locations[i][0] + "</h5>" + "<div id='bodyContent'><img src='" + locations[i][3] + "' width='120' height='120' alt='' /></div></div>");
                //infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);

                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(null);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
        map.setTilt(65);
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(loclat, loclon);
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
       // map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
        marker.setMap(map);
    });
}
```